# next() to intermediate Observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I'm new to RxJS so my terminology may not be concise, sorry. I created derived Observable with **map()** and want it to keep passing it's source values through itself along with additional events on top of that. For example:

```
//receiving values from server:
const $source = new Rx.Subject;

//map from network representation to client one:
const $client = $source.map( server => server.x + server.y );
//display on screen:
$client.subscribe( client => console.log( "client:", client ) )

//have input to update client-side representation:
const $button = new Rx.Subject;
$button.subscribe( $client );

$button.next( { x : 1, y : 2 } );
```

Sadly, it prints "3" instead of Object as if **$button** sends events directly to **$source** instead of **$client**. Why does **$button.next(...)** emits to **$source** instead of emitting to **$client**? I expected an operator (**map()** in this case) to spawn new stream. How can I implement a local cycle still making it dependent on original stream, but without modifying that original stream? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you are seeing is expected, and what you are trying to achieve is not possible.

> I expected an operator (map() in this case) to spawn new stream.

This is correct, **however** the newly spawned stream is an extension to `source$`, so:

```
$client = $source + map
// this means any data injected into client$
// will walk through an instance of source$ and then through the map-function
```

I know, this only explains the behavior, and does not provide a "solution" - however, to properly provide a good answer that *solves* your issue, you should write something about what you are trying to achieve - unless all you wanted was to understand why it was this way.

Also: The way it is currently structured looks really overly complicated and i'm sure this could be simplified if you provided some information on the usecase.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just want to let user change value starting from the server one, but anytime server sends any new value - reset what user sees and continue changing from already new one.

Comment: Well, but that's what your streams currently do - maybe you should have a look at your `map`-method, are you sure you want to add `x` and `y`? Maybe that is your issue? Please update your question with a stream-diagram of the following: What data-sources emit which data when, and what data do you expect to show up at the end of the stream.

Comment: Your explanation of **map()** being an **extension** (whatever it is) to original Observable made me to figure out the solution. Posted it as an answer, thank you.

Comment: Awesome!! finding a solution on yourself is always the best experience :-)

Answer (score 0):

Adding intermediate Subject (**$anotherSource**) and merging the along with original **$source** solves the issue:

```
//eternal values receive from server:
const $source = new Rx.Subject;
$source.subscribe( () => console.log( "Should not" ) );

const $anotherSource = new Rx.Subject;

//map from network representation:
const $client = $source.map( server => server.x + server.y ).merge( $anotherSource );
//display on screen:
$client.subscribe( client => console.log( "client:", client ) )

//have input to update client-side representation interleaving with server one:
const $button = new Rx.Subject;
$button.subscribe( $anotherSource );

$button.next( { x : 1, y : 2 } );
```

**$client** now receives an Objects instead of "3" as expected.